# Ionic Native Storage Blocking DOM UI

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5, cordova-nativestorage

After shifting from @ionic/storage to @ionic-native/native-storage (since we only use Android and iOS), the native-storage they said its faster, but when we storing some data and retrieving it, it's blocking the DOM UI.

```js
//Following is how i used to call getItem from native storage
//from the return to the then value, it tooks 4 seconds, and my data is not that large, and it freeze my //DOM UI
 getDeployments():Promise<Deployment[]> {
    return this.storage.getItem('deployments').then((value) => { 
      return Promise.resolve(value);//JSON.parse(value);
    },(err) => {
      console.log(err);
     return Promise.resolve([]) 
      //throw new Error('Error fetching deployment');
    });
  }
```

Is this an expected behaviour, or has my way of calling the `getItem` from storage got an issue?

I am using 5.22.0

Comment: For sure its unexpected behavior, maybe use npm rm cordova natuve storage then npm rm @native storage files then reinstall them both, since maybe there a certain bug in installation.

Comment: Hello @Jasonz, Welcome to Stackoverflow. Always add your code language it will help others to identify keywords and normal words.

Comment: I tried remove whole platform and node_modules, and reinstall npm modules, and re-add platforms, but still to get the stored data takes time, and during this time, my UI is blocking(freezes)